# How to get calculations from two rows

Tags: sql, date-arithmetic

I started learning SQL recently and would like to know if it is possible to do the calculations as below.

Basically my table looks like this:

```
id    Date           Fill_nbr     
 1   01/01/2015       30      
 1   02/05/2015       30      
 1   03/02/2015       30      
 1   07/01/2015       30      
 1   07/26/2015       30      
 2   03/01/2015       30      
 ....
```

And I'd like to create a table like this:

```
 id  Date             Fill_nbr     Date_last      Gap    First
 1   01/01/2015       30           01/30/2015      0         1
 1   02/05/2015       30           03/04/2015      5         0
 1   03/02/2015       30           03/31/2015      0         0
 1   07/01/2015       30           07/30/2015      91        1
 1   07/26/2015       30           08/24/2015      0         0
 2   03/01/2015       30           03/30/2015      0         1
 ....
```

The rule for column 'Date_last' is Date_last = Date + fill_nbr which is easy to get.

The difficult part for me is the 'Gap' part. The rules are:

- Gap='Date' - last record of "Date_last'. 
    For example, gap for the second row is calculated as Gap=02/05/2015-
    01/30/2015;
- Gap=0 for everyone's first record or when the calculated gap<0;

The rule for column 'First':

- First=1 for everyone's first record OR when gap>60.
- Otherwise, First=0;

Comment: Please include the your query as far as you have it

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: I can see how line #2 gets a gap of 5 days, but how is the 91 computed?

Comment: @Chuck The 91 is calculated as 07/01/2015-03/31/2015=91

Comment: @Jenna, are you using SQL server, to bad both dates are not on the same row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like this question is about abandoned already since important details are still missing...thought it'd be interesting to at least find a solution. The solution below works for SQL Server 2012 or higher since it uses `LAG`.

```
SELECT
  id,
  [Date],
  Fill_nbr,
  (CASE WHEN LAG (DATEADD(DD, Fill_nbr - 1, [Date]), 1, NULL) OVER (
    PARTITION BY id ORDER BY [Date]) > [Date] THEN 0 ELSE
      COALESCE(DATEDIFF(DD, LAG (DATEADD(DD, Fill_nbr - 1, [Date]), 1, NULL) OVER (
      PARTITION BY id ORDER BY [Date]), [Date]) - 1, 0) END) AS Gap,
  DATEADD(DD, Fill_nbr - 1, [Date]) AS Date_last,
  CASE WHEN DATEPART(DD, [Date]) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS [First]
FROM Records
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a9b68/8

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, Jason! I figured it out that the LAG or LEAD functions would work for this problem. So here is my solution which is similar with yours. Thanks again for your input!

```
select
   id,
   date,
   fill_nbr,
   date + fill_nbr - 1 AS date_last,
   LAG(date_last) OVER (PARTITION BY id OREDER by id, date) LagV,
   date - LagV - 1 as gap,
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id IRDER BY id, date) AS rk,
   CASE
       WHEN (gap>30 or rk=1) then '1'
       ELSE '0'
   END AS first 
FROM table;
```